# Problem with url in alerts

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, outlook

I get alerts after changes to a list.
Immediate alerts work well, that is to say in the url that appear "to change the settings of my alerts" or "display ...", the path appears much like this (for example) : `http://shp2013/Lists/ModifCat/DispForm.aspx?ID=389`

But when it is a daily or weekly alert, this is what appears in the url: `/Lists/ModifCat`
In reality it lacks the `http://shp2013`

How is this possible? where could be the problem?

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution, I installed the update: KB2768000